# OWL restrictions value vs only vs exactly on dataProperty

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

Suppose we have a class named `A`, and a **DataProperty** called `hasRestriction`. What is the difference between these statements:

```
A SubClassOf (hasRestriction value 2)   
A SubClassOf (hasRestriction exactly 2)  
A SubClassOf (hasRestriction only 2)
```

Comment: what is the relation here? I mean, the class relation between `A` and the complex class expression is missing ... like `A SubClassOf (hasRestriction value 2)`

Comment: and the difference is obvious, the 1. axiom infers that each individual of `A` has - among others - a concrete value 2 for the property `hasRestriction`.

Comment: the other cases are ambigue in your current syntax - it's not clear what you try to say. If case 2 means `A SubClassOf (hasRestriction exactly 2)` it means each individual of `A` has two values for the properties, both just unknown.

Comment: the latter if `A SubClassOf (hasRestriction only {2})` is equivalent to case 1.) - the `values` construct was just introduced as syntactic sugar for it.

Comment: thanks,plz send your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** read AKSW's comments, they are good and concise.

**Long version:**
Your question is asking how to interpret class expressions in Protégé. Protégé uses the OWL 2 Manchester syntax to describe classes, and Protégé assumes that ontologies are interpreted according to the [OWL 2 Direct Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/). If the property `hasRestriction` is a DataProperty in Protégé, then it means that `hasRestriction` denotes a set of pairs (*x*,*y*) where *x* is an individual (an element of the universe of discourse) and *y* is a data value (like a number, a string, a date). In Protégé, class expressions are used to denote sets of individuals.

In the statements you provide there are three class expressions:

```
hasRestriction value 2   
hasRestriction exactly 2  
hasRestriction only 2
```

The first one, `hasRestriction value 2`, identifies the set of things that have the property `hasRestriction` with the value 2. So if *x* belongs to this class, then (*x*, 2) belongs to what `hasRestriction` denotes. If `A` is a subClass of this class, then a triple `x rdf:type A` entails the triple `x hasRestriction 2`.

The second one, `hasRestriction exactly 2`, identifies the set of things that have exactly 2 values for the property `hasRestriction`. So if *x* belongs to this class, then there are two distinct values *v* and *w* such that (*x*, *v*) and (*x*,*w*) belong to what `hasRestriction` denotes. If `A` is a subClass of this class, then a triple `x rdf:type A` entails the triples `x hasRestriction _:v` and `x hasRestriction _:w` and `_:v owl:differentFrom _:w` (I use a quasi-Turtle syntax here).

The third one, `hasRestriction only 2` is a syntax error because if `hasRestriction` is a datatype property, then you must use a datatype expression after the keyword `only`. For instance, `hasRestriction only xsd:integer`.

In the second case, a given individual `x` in class `A` may have known values for the property `hasRestriction`. For instance, there could be the triples `x rdf:type A`, `x hasRestriction 1`, `x hasRestriction 2`, in which case, we know that `x` exactly has 1 and 2 as values for `hasRestriction`. If, additionally, we know that `x hasRestriction 3`, then there is a contradiction, because 1, 2 and 3 are three distinct values, while the expression tells us that there must be *exactly* two.